# need to center a list in the center of a web page

Tags: css, html, center

I need to create a list in an html page and have it centered using CSS.

Here's an image of sorta what i want:

[image]

the little block list should be in the center, with all of the solid bullets and there text left aligned, but the block itself should still be in the center .  i have my list created and the indents i want, and the entire list is left aligned.

basically i want the list in the dead center of the page, with the bullets all left aligned correctly with each other and the two circle bullets indented a bit.

how can i do this!?

I'm trying a `div` using `margin-left/right` set to `auto` but having no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `margin:0 auto;`
Usually this works to make stuff in center.

Comment: make sure to give the block element a width though.

Comment: yes, almost positive ive tried this in my div{} part of my css, no luck

Comment: thank you thescientist, adding the width:450px; line has made it line up correctly, now i just have to get the input button to line up

Comment: this one worked the best. you just have to assign a width, then it centered perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>One</li>
                <li>Two</li>       
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
    width:45%;
    border:1px solid red;
    padding:1em;
    margin:0 auto;
}​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7rrzZ/1/

Of course, you don't want the border and you will need to play with the bullets, but you get the idea.

Comment: this kind of works, but when i maximize the page the text is still a bit to the left and not really centered

Answer (score 1):

This way it's centred exactly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <style>
        body { text-align: center; }
        div { display: inline-block; }
        li { text-align: left; }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div> 
         <ul>
           <li>text
              <ul>
                 <li>indented text</li>
                 <li>indented text</li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li>text
             <ul>
               <li>indented text</li>
               <li>indented text</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
         </ul>  
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by adding padding-left in CSS to the div element that contains the list. I used percentages (in my case 44%). You can adjust the percentages depending on the length of the text. Nothing more was needed for me to center the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That kinda works but is a bit laborious and would require changes every time the content of the `<li />` tags changes.